# Document creation with same Id across partition failing

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We are trying to create document with same Id across different partitions

The update fails with error

In Azure Cosmos

```
{
    "code": 409,
    "body": {
        "code": "Conflict",
        "message": "Entity with the specified id already exists in the system., \r\nRequestStartTime: 2019-12-19T08:34:37.5860449Z, RequestEndTime: 2019-12-19T08:34:37.5961787Z, Number of regions attempted:1\r\nResponseTime: 2019-12-19T08:34:37.5961787Z, StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://cdb-ms-prod-westus1-fd41.documents.azure.com:14086/apps/06af805e-8590-4705-9817-859c9fa7bdc4/services/fb1ffb13-843f-4459-b668-80186964b5fc/partitions/ca683c98-0daf-42f9-8408-cecff98b3d7f/replicas/132212042754425215p/, LSN: 3, GlobalCommittedLsn: 3, PartitionKeyRangeId: 0, IsValid: True, StatusCode: 409, SubStatusCode: 3302, RequestCharge: 1.57, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: -1#3, UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, ResourceType: Document, OperationType: Create\r\n, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.7.0"
    },
    "headers": {
        <snipped>
    },
    "activityId": "3182f9a5-6c44-48e9-85af-642fcc1b0b86",
    "substatus": 3302
}
```

In Emulator
Document creation error for container Collection_L1_Test - file docDbBug.txt:

```
{
    "code": 409,
    "body": "{\"code\":\"Conflict\",\"message\":\"Message: {\\\"Errors\\\":[\\\"Resource with specified id or name already exists.\\\",\\\"Resource with id already exists with a conflicting hashed partition key, Please retry with a different partition key.\\\"]}\\r\\nActivityId: f8e002d8-04e9-4a69-821b-01ca483f8789, Request URI: /apps/DocDbApp/services/DocDbServer12/partitions/a4cb4958-38c8-11e6-8106-8cdcd42c33be/replicas/1p/, RequestStats: \\r\\nRequestStartTime: 2019-12-19T08:13:52.5769961Z, RequestEndTime: 2019-12-19T08:13:52.5779926Z, Number of regions attempted:1\\r\\nResponseTime: 2019-12-19T08:13:52.5779926Z, StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://127.0.0.1:10253/apps/DocDbApp/services/DocDbServer12/partitions/a4cb4958-38c8-11e6-8106-8cdcd42c33be/replicas/1p/, LSN: 203, GlobalCommittedLsn: -1, PartitionKeyRangeId: 1, IsValid: True, StatusCode: 409, SubStatusCode: 3302, RequestCharge: 1.57, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: 203, UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, ResourceType: Document, OperationType: Create\\r\\n, SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.7.0\"}",
    "activityId": "f8e002d8-04e9-4a69-821b-01ca483f8789",
    "substatus": 3302
}
```

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys it looks like uniqueness of Id is at a partition level from the above experiment it looks like 
Id needs to be unique at a collection level

Is it not safe to assume that partition key + id is a unique combination inside a collection?

P.S. repro can be achieved by adding docDbBug.txt first to a cosmos DB (type SQL) and then trying to add docDbBugUpdate.txt in the same collection 
(both files are attached)

Comment: Sharing file at https://gist.github.com/gauravsaralMs/42d12def83c5e56dd2390dffe38f72a7 and https://gist.github.com/gauravsaralMs/c21b901d37d7f4af738ffa3cb828fcc9

Comment: Please edit your question to contain specifics, such as the partition key your collection has, as well as the partition key values you're attempting to use. As written though, your question is just two (very lengthy and unreadable) error messages. I edited the error message formatting for readability (including removing all the returned headers, for clarity) but it's still not clear what, exactly, you're attempting. There should be no need for someone to click through to an external site to view additional content; all relevant content to the issue should be placed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

A document can be uniquely identified by using a combination of id and partitionkey in a Cosmos DB collection.

The issue here could be due to a very large partition key value.

*"If there are multiple partition keys that have the same first 100 bytes, then those logical partitions are considered as the same logical partition by the service".* Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/large-partition-keys